# Use-case for iptables rule

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

If OUTPUT chain default policy is ACCEPT, is there any use case for the following rule?

```
-A OUTPUT -o $INTIF -s $EXTIP -d $INTNET -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

Some simple tools use this as a way to count traffic matching a particular rule.
There can be other rules later which would block packets if they are not explicitly allowed earlier.

Comment: Still I don't understand in which cases I may have a packet, coming out of LAN, which has src ip of WAN and directed to LAN devices.

Comment: @Michael: There may be a NAT rule for LAN based packets sent to the external IP (web, mail server, etc.).  This would count those packets.